# Does __bread() always return PAGE_SIZE number of bytes?

Tags: io, linux-kernel

The Linux kernel API has a __bread method:

```
__bread(struct block_device *bdev, sector_t block, unsigned size)
```

which returns a buffer_head pointer whose  data field contains **size** worth of data.However, I noticed that reading beyond **size** bytes still gave me valid data up to PAGE_SIZE number of bytes. This got me wondering if I can presume the buffer_head returned by a *__bread* always contains valid data worth PAGE_SIZE bytes even if the **size** argument passed to it is lesser.

Or maybe it was just a coincidence.

Comment: I'd think, the answer is no: What if the file you read contained less than PAGE_SIZE amount of bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The __bread perform a read IO from given block interface, but depending on the backing store, you get different results.

For harddrives, the block device will fetch data in sector sizes. Usually this is either 512 bytes or 4K. If 512 bytes, and you ask for 256 bytes, you'll be able to access the last parts of the sector. Thus, you may fetch up to the sector size.  However, it is not always true. With memory backed devices, you may only access the 256 bytes, as it is not served up by the block layer, but by the VSL.

In short, no. You should not rely on this feature, as it depends on which block device is backing the storage and may also change with block layer implementation.

Comment: I was reading from a FAT32 disk with a sector size of 512 bytes and a 'cluster' size of 4k.Though I requested 512 bytes via __bread,I got 4K worth of valid data.So maybe for hard drives,maybe it returns block-size (as opposed to sector size) worth of data? Of course,the upper limit being the page-size,which was 4k on my system.

Comment: You're right about data being fetched from the disk in chunks of sector size.Verified this by checking the value of 'bh->b_size' member upon reading from 512 byte and 4K sector size disks.